# Cannot download silverlight-embedded Microsoft Project 2010 demo videos

Tags: video, download, embedded, microsoft-project, silverlight

I need to download the demo videos at my office so that I can view it later at home since I have slow internet connection there but it seems to be no way to download the videos at [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20110524170853/http://www.microsoft.com:80/showcase/en/US/search?phrase=%22project%20conference%202009%22), and other resources in [this site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrisfie/microsoft-project-2010-resources-and-content-april-2010).

Using some of the Firefox addons to download them is not possible. Do you have any tips for me?

Please share.

ps. I'm looking for free/open-source solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft movies are in Silverlight format. Orbit Downloader seems to be able to do it.

See:

[How to Download movie from Silverlight Free](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/silverlight-downloader/download-movie-from-silverlight-free.htm)

Comment: Your suggestion is a virusl-containing software!? Please see the scanned report here on virustotal http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=39109b8594c1bf4090c0b406b088f96503123a8ed3f7670bd56a79204e44c48f-1295300601

Comment: @Nam Gi VU: Orbit Downloader is a [well-known](http://download.cnet.com/Orbit-Downloader/3000-2071_4-10981056.html) product, downloaded hundreds of thousands times. The eSafe anti-virus engine has surely found a false positive.

Comment: We still not sure if it is clean though :( However, I have installed it and love the feature when it suggest me with the update list of my current software.

Comment: I tried to use Orbit but Grab++ still cannot detect & help me to download the video which I want to download here http://cdn-smooth.ms-studiosmedia.com/msstudios/Project2010/Default.html. Do you have any idea Harry?

Comment: I find it strange the Orbit can't detect the stream. Did you wait until the video really started? In any case, querying google for "download silverlight movie" gets several commercial products that you could try.

Comment: Today I've succeeded download embedded Silverlight videos on another sites. Thanks!